# Select a product from a table with 2 property joined

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a mysql table like this

```
PRODUCT
-------
product_id: 1 | name: product .... product_id: 2 | name: product2 .. etc etc
```

then i have another table

```
PROPERTY
---
id: 1 | name: red | product_id: 1 .... id: 2 | name: large | product_id: 1 ..... id: 3 | name : brown | product_id: 2 .... and so on ...
```

How can i select a product with 2 property?

For example i want to take a product with RED and LARGE property

i tried

```
SELECT * FROM product
JOIN property USING (product_id)
WHERE property.name = "red" AND property.name = "large" ....
```

but obviusly it doesn't work :)

thanks for the help and sorry for my english!

Comment: check my answer below, you need to group the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to count its instances of its record

```
SELECT  a.productname
FROM    product a
        INNER JOIN property b
            on a.product_ID = b.product_ID
WHERE b.name IN ('red', 'large')
GROUP BY a.productname
HAVING COUNT(a.productname) = 2
```

if you click the demo, you can see the differences between grouping the result and by regular filetering using `IN`

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e491b/7)

Comment: I prefer this solution to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM product
JOIN property USING (product_id)
WHERE property.name = "red" OR property.name = "large" ....
```

Additionally, you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM product
JOIN property USING (product_id)
WHERE property.name IN ('red', 'large') ....
```

Comment: i need the product with both the property :) with OR / IN the query take all products with 'red' ... and all products with 'large'. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM product p
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * 
                 FROM property a
                WHERE a.name = 'red' 
                  AND a.product_id = p.product_id)
   AND EXISTS( SELECT * 
                 FROM property a
                WHERE a.name ='large' 
                  AND a.product_id = p.product_id)
```

could work?